# Responsive design on 50%-width boxes

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes, each with `width: 50%;`, placed next to each other with `float`. One has a white background, the other a grey background.

As the page width shrinks the boxes stay beside each other. At some minimum size I don't want the boxes to get any smaller. Here they should jump down under each other.

They do this fine. But the white and grey boxes keep their 50% width - at this point they should rather fill the whole width 100%.

[The issue is seen here](http://testmiljo.eosweb.dk/) just below the video.

(The min-width does not do any difference here at the moment, and is just set to some arbitrary value (100px) on the page.)

What is the proper way for this responsive effect, so the products are full-sized on small screen but can stand beside each other on large screens?

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to approach this from a mobile-first setup. Set the boxes to 100% width until the breakpoint where you want them to start forming columns. For example,if you wanted them to start forming columns at 600px device-width and greater:

```
.column_selector {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
@media all and (min-device-width: 600px) {

    .column_selector {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Also, if you're going to use percentages for widths, I'd recommend using `box-sizing: border-box` to account for the padding in your width calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@media` to set some special rules for different window dimensions. Something like:

```
.div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .div1 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .div2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e025L2ny/).